# He creado un cronómetro con Javascript, y me gustaría que cada 5 segundos cambie de color

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var segundos = 0;
var minutos = 0;

function inicio() {

  control = setInterval(cronometro, 1000);
  document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = false;
}

function parar() {

  clearInterval(control);
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = false;
}

function reinicio() {
  clearInterval(control);
  segundos = 0;
  minutos = 0;
  document.getElementById('Tiempo').innerHTML = ("0" + minutos + ":" + "0" + segundos);

  document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = true;
}

function cronometro() {

  segundos += 1;

  if (segundos == 60) {

    segundos = 0;
    minutos += 1;
  }

  if (segundos < 10 && minutos < 10) {
    document.getElementById('Tiempo').innerHTML = ("0" + minutos + ":" + "0" + segundos);
  } else if (segundos >= 10 && minutos < 10) {
    document.getElementById('Tiempo').innerHTML = ("0" + minutos + ":" + segundos);
  } else if (segundos < 10 && minutos > 10) {
    document.getElementById('Tiempo').innerHTML = (+minutos + ":" + "0" + segundos);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Tiempo').innerHTML = (minutos + ":" + segundos);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p id="Tiempo">00:00</p>


  <input type="button" class="boton" id="inicio" value="Start &#9658;" onclick="inicio();">
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="parar" value="Stop &#8718;" onclick="parar();" disabled>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="continuar" value="Resume &#8634;" onclick="inicio();" disabled>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="reinicio" value="Reset &#8635;" onclick="reinicio();" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: que cambie de color que parte?

Comment: Quiero que cambie el reloj

Comment: que cambie solo la primera vez o que siempre cada 5 segundos este cambiando?

Comment: Cada cinco segundo que cambie cada vez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo que Alo Malbarez te dijo, o también puedes hacer un intervalo, algo como esto:

```
const randomColor = () => {

    return "#" + (random = (color) => {

        const characters = "1234567890abcdef".split("");
        const randomCharacter = characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)];
        color += randomCharacter;

        if (color.length !==6) {
            return random(color);
        }

        return color; 

    })("");

}

const cambiarColor = setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementById("Tiempo").style.color = randomColor();
}, 5000);
```

También ten en cuenta que si lo que quieres es cambiar el color del fondo, entonces usa style.backgroundColor. Y cuando el cronómetro pare, debes hacer:

```
clearInterval(cambiarColor);
```

Answer (score 5):

cada 5 segundos: `(segundos%5==0)`

cambiar color: `document.getElementById("Tiempo").style.color`

color al azar en hexa: `"#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);`

todo junto:

```
if (segundos%5==0) {
   document.getElementById("Tiempo").style.color = "#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
```

Comment: me causa duda lo he probado pero el color solo cambia una vez, ¿cómo se debe implementar??

Comment: dentro del loop cuando cambia el innerhtml